# How Wireshark could read data from other ips

Tags: networking, security, wireshark, packet-capture

When I open wireshark I could see the packets send by machines other than mine. How could its possible?

Example

```
8252    99.150192   somoeneip   239.255.255.250 SSDP    NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1 
8253    99.151204   fe8s0::15s34:12c8:2f2132:d99221 ff02::c SSDP    NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1 
8075    96.624367   otherip 239.255.255.250 SSDP    NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1
```

Values are modified for privacy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a peek at those IP addresses.  They're within one of the [reserved IP address blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses): the [multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) block.

> multicast is the delivery of a message or information to a group of destination computers simultaneously in a single transmission from the source

The reason you're seeing those packets from other machines is because they're being sent to anyone listening.